# Hi guys pls how do i acces a class property from another class in qt c++ ve tried but it give me an empty string and a 0 value when i try to -

Tags: qt, c++11

```
class Dialog : QDialog { 
public:
    QString prodname;

    qint32 id;
}
```

Here is the implementation.

```
void Dialog::on_clicked(){
    Prodname = ui->qty_label->text(); 

    id = ui->id_label->text().toint();
}
```

But when I access it from another class:

```
#include dialog.h

void secwin::on_clicked(){
    Dialog dlg;

    Ui->qty->settext(dlg.Prodname);

    Ui->id->settext (QString::number (dlg.id);
}
```

Comment: if you want to set attributes of your class, there is a `convenient` way in qt, `setPropertie` or Q_PROPERTY(...). this property consists of getters and setters, notifiers (signals), etc. a distinction is also made between public and private slots, i don't know your project. but it could be that you have attributes or methods as private

Comment: You are creating a new instance of the `Dialog` class every time you enter `secwin::on_clicked`. Is that what you want?

Comment: You probably meant to actually run the dialog, as in `dlg.exec()`, before accessing those members. They are apparently only populated after the dialog is shown and the user clicks something.